# Flutter ShareIntent is opening different App in production

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, dart, share-intent

I am using the [receiving_share_intent](https://pub.dev/documentation/receive_sharing_intent/latest/) in my app so users can share anything into my app. That is working fine, but I just got a mail from a user where another app called "draw names" is opened when tapping on my app (called "Wishlists").

I just tested it my self and it's true.

[image]

How can that happen? For the `app_group` I am using the *best practice*:

group.my_bundle_id

How can that happen and what can I do to prevent that behvaior?

Comment: If you have used the example `CFBundleURLSchemes` of `sharemedia` then the chance is that the other app has also used this scheme.

Comment: @Paulw11 I do have `ShareMedia` as `CFBundleURLSchemes` but I would have guessed that Apple would linke the app via the bundleId or something. So anyone with the same scheme has this problem? Sounds weird to me

Comment: Nope. It is the url scheme that is used. Make sure your url scheme is likely to be unique.